# remove tagged master project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I dont know how it happend but im getting a tag "master" in my IntelliJ and I want to make it disappear. How may I do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU, this appears in the Project view. Most likely you have some plugin (e.g. GitToolbox) that shows it.

If it is GitToolBox, it should be configurable via Settings. Otherwise, just uninstall the plugin.